# Using Beautiful Soup, how do I iterate over all embedded text?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Let's say I wanted to remove vowels from HTML:

```
<a href="foo">Hello there!</a>Hi!
```

becomes

```
<a href="foo">Hll thr!</a>H!
```

I figure this is a job for Beautiful Soup. How can I select the text in between tags and operate on it like this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Suppose the variable `test_html` has the following html content:

```
<html>
<head><title>Test title</title></head>
<body>
<p>Some paragraph</p>
Useless Text
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Some link</a>not a link
<a href="http://python.org">Another link</a>
</body></html>
```

Just do this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

test_html = load_html_from_above()
soup = BeautifulSoup(test_html)

for t in soup.findAll(text=True):
    text = unicode(t)
    for vowel in u'aeiou':
        text = text.replace(vowel, u'') 
    t.replaceWith(text)

print soup
```

That prints:

```
<html>
<head><title>Tst ttl</title></head>
<body>
<p>Sm prgrph</p>
Uslss Txt
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Sm lnk</a>nt  lnk
<a href="http://python.org">Anthr lnk</a>
</body></html>
```

Note that the tags and attributes are untouched.